Where do the Christmas-themed minifigs on the 2024 catalogue come from?
The cover image of the September to December 2024 catalogue (at least the German one) shows, in its bottom right area, a couple of Christmas-themed minifigures:

The Santa minifigure appears to be the one from the City advent calendar.
Even though it would be a nice idea to have an advent calendar with only special Christmas minifigures, this is not the case for this year's advent calendar. I have gone through all the pages of the catalogue multiple times, but I could not find any other set that contains these other minifigures, either.
I seem to recognize two of them from earlier sets, though:

The gingerbread woman looks like the one from the Gingerbread House from 2019.
And the yeti looks just like the one included in a minifigure series from 2013.

But surely, Lego wouldn't adorn their new catalogue with images of products that have already gone out of production ... or would they?
Is there any (new?) set available in 2024 that contains these other Christmas-themed minifigures, maybe a Lego exclusive that is not listed in the general catalogue?

The rest of the minifigures in that image (the snowman, reindeer costume, and sugar fairy) are all part of the Series 23 collectible minifigures, released in 2022.

Disappointing (I had hoped for a "secret" Christmas-themed minifig-scale playset - or, at the very least, for a way to buy the products depicted on the cover of the catalogue -, but apparently true. Accepted.
